# Replace three dashes, but only if significant characters follow in the same line

Tags: python, regex

In a multiline text, I would like to replace triple dashes, `---`, by `X`. There need to be exactly three dashed in a row, not two or four. Another restriction: If `---` is the last character in the line (except possible trailing whitespace), don't replace it.

So far, I got

```py
import re

text1 = "a---b"
text2 = "a\n  --- \nb"

for text in [text1, text2]:
    print(repr(re.sub("(?<!-)---(?!-)", "X", text)))
```

```
'aXb'
'a\n  X \nb'
```

with negative lookahead/lookbehind. I would like to have

```
'aXb'
'a\n  --- \nb'
```

though. How to I implement the rule that significant characters need follow the `---`?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs. It's not always clear what shape of data you are trying to work with just from a description.

Comment: Just add your condition to negatige lookahead: [`(?<!-)---(?!-|\s*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/GkEUbY/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert that to the left are optional whitespace chars without newlines followed by a non whitespace char that is not a hyphen

```
(?<!-)---(?=[^\S\n]*[^-\s])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LgBMV8/1)

```
for text in [text1, text2]:
    print(repr(re.sub(r"(?<!-)---(?=[^\S\n]*[^-\s])", "X", text)))
```

Output

```
'aXb'
'a\n  --- \nb'
```

---

Or you can assert not trailing spaces without newlines till the end of the string:

```
(?<!-)---(?!-|[^\S\n]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a0hb91/1)

```
for text in [text1, text2]:
    print(repr(re.sub(r"(?m)(?<!-)---(?=[^\S\n]*[^-\s])", "X", text)))
```

Output

```
'aXb'
'a\n  --- \nb'
```

Comment: Only the first solution appears to work.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer The second pattern uses an anchor, so you would have to enable multiline with `(?m)` or `re.MULTILINE`